# How to get a singular value from a list of tuples?

Tags: python

For example lets say I have

```
tuple_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

How would I get a single value from one of them?

For example if I want just the 'a' and not the 1, I can't do:

```
tuple_list[0]
```

Because that would return:

```
('a', 1)
```

So my question is, how can I make it return only 'a' or 'b' or 1 or 2?

Comment: tuples are indexed just like lists. `tuple_list[0]` returns a tuple... how would you get the first value from that returned tuple?

Comment: If you just want the `a` in `('a', 1)`, you can do `tuple_list[0][0]`

Comment: It is not clear how you want to select the single value that you want. E.g., you can ask for the `2` value like "I want the second item in the second tuple" (that would be tuple_list[1][1]), or it might be that you're asking "I want to consider this a list of 6 items and get the 4th item from it". A bit trickier, but this will do it: list(itertools.chain(*tuple_list))[3]. Or, maybe the way you want to pick it neither of these - please update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are indexed the same way that lists are (their difference being that lists are mutable). So, if you have a list of tuples, you can access the individual elements the same way you would access the elements of a list.

For example,

```
>> x = [('a', 0), ('b', 1)]
>> x
 [('a', 0), ('b', 1)]   

>> type(x)
<class 'list'>   

>> type(x[0])
<class 'tuple'>   

>> type((x[0])[0])        # which is equivalent to
<class 'str'>   

>> type(x[0][0])
<class 'str'>   

>> x[0][0]
'a'
```

Therefore, if you need the `i`th element of a tuple that is the `j`th element of a list `x`, you access it with `x[j][i]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
tuple_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c',3)]

print(tuple_list)

print("Tuple [0][0] = ", end = ' ')
print(tuple_list[0][0])
print("Tuple [0][1] = ", end = ' ')
print(tuple_list[0][1])
print("Tuple [1][0] = ", end = ' ')
print(tuple_list[1][0])
print("Tuple [1][1] = ", end = ' ')
print(tuple_list[1][1])
print("Tuple [2][0] = ", end = ' ')
print(tuple_list[2][0])
print("Tuple [2][1] = ", end = ' ')
print(tuple_list[2][1])
```

**Output**

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/LPTHW$ python3.7 compare.py 
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
Tuple [0][0] =  a
Tuple [0][1] =  1
Tuple [1][0] =  b
Tuple [1][1] =  2
Tuple [2][0] =  c
Tuple [2][1] =  3
```

This should give you a good visual representation of how to get to each item, pretty much think of it like:

```
lista =   (0,     1,     2)
lista =([a, b], [c, d],[e, f])
```

Imagine these two overlayed now we know `list[0] = 0` , That you already have shown to understand, now `list[0]` has two subcomponents `list[0][0]` = `a` and `list[0][1]` = `b` representing the first and second `items` of `list[0]`. And `list[0]` will represent `(a,b)`.

Did this help?